# Applications running in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background

I have an application which must collect user data.as possible collect data user when the application is turned off?I've read on the topic background modes but I did not find the solution to your case. Planned to collect information constantly when the phone is work and outputting the information to widget in notification center. how to do it?